# GMSPath in swift Codable does not conform to protocol swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, gmsplace

I created a model and used codable with it. I am currently using GMSPath to get path, but on adding to the model class, I get the error  `Type 'EstimateResponse' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'` and  `Type 'EstimateResponse' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'`

below is my Model

```
class EstimateResponse: Codable {

    var path: GMSPath? // Set by Google directions API call
    var destination: String?
    var distance: String?
}
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: i guess you have to follow the manual way not with codable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GMSPath` has an [`encodedPath`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_path.html#a9b5b3808fbdc30e21a4b9d53e70058f7) property (which is a string), and it can also be initialised with an encoded path. You just need to encode your `GMSPath` to its encoded path representation.

Conform `EstimateResponse` to `Codable` with explicit implementations:

```
class EstimateResponse : Codable {
    var path: GMSPath?
    var destination: String?
    var distance: String?

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case path, destination, distance
    }
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let encodedPath = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .path)
        path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: encodedPath)
        destination = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .destination)
        distance = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .distance)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = try encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(path?.encodedPath(), forKey: .path)
        try container.encode(destination, forKey: .destination)
        try container.encode(distance, forKey: .distance)
    }
}
```

Comment: This gave a few errors `Argument type '() -> String' does not conform to expected type 'Encodable'`

`A non-failable initializer cannot delegate to failable initializer 'init(fromEncodedPath:)' written with 'init?'`

`Designated initializer cannot be declared in an extension of 'GMSPath'; did you mean this to be a convenience initializer?`

Comment: This is another error `Initializer requirement 'init(from:)' can only be satisfied by a 'required' initializer in the definition of non-final class 'GMSPath'`

Comment: @King Just do what the error says. Add the word `required`.

Comment: WHere @Sweeper?

Comment: `'required' initializer must be declared directly in class 'GMSPath' (not in an extension)`

Comment: Obviously `GMSPath` cannot be extended with required initializers.

Comment: @vadian my thoughts too. but what do you suggest going forward?

Comment: @King Alternatively, manually conform `EstimateResponse` to `Codable`. See the edit.

Comment: @Sweeper is this line intentional as it shouldnot be `try container.encode(path?.encodedPath(), forKey: .encodedPath)`

Comment: @vadian can you provide an answer as per your explanation. It would definately help

Comment: encode `Reference to member 'encodedPath' cannot be resolved without a contextual type`

Comment: @King Sweeper's solution is better than the conversion to `[CLLocationCooordinate2D]`

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper. This works. Could there be a work around as if the model contains a lot of values. it would not be convenient to write doing keys for everything

Comment: @King I don't know of any. However, if you only need to encode the data, you can conform `GMSPath` and `EstimateResponse` to `Encodable`, and use the solution I presented before. Since it's just `Encodable`, you won't have trouble with the initialiser.